# Simple PathView with centered Current Item

Tags: qt, qml, carousel

I've just started programming in QML and I need to make a simple Carousel with some images. I've found that the simplest way to do that is to use a PathView. According to that I've tried to make my current item on the center of the view,failing. Here's the code I've done.

```
Rectangle {
    id: rectangle
    height: 200
    color: "#00000000"
    Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
    Layout.fillWidth: true

    PathView {
        id: carouselView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: listModel

        delegate: Image {
            width: PathView.isCurrentItem ? 256 : 128
            height: PathView.isCurrentItem ? 256 : 128
            source: iconSource
        }
        path: Path {
            startX: 0
            PathLine {
                x: 800
                y: 0
            }
        }
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignVCenter
    }
}

ListModel {
    id: listModel
    ListElement {
        iconSource: "qrc:///images/chair.svg"
    }
    ListElement {
        iconSource: "qrc:///images/chair.svg"
    }
    ListElement {
        iconSource: "qrc:///images/chair.svg"
    }
    ListElement {
        iconSource: "qrc:///images/chair.svg"
    }
}
```

The desired effect is a simple horizontal carousel with a centered current item. 
Current version used : 5.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple carousel example using PathView:

```js
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 640
    Component {
        id: delegate
        Item {
            width: 200; height: 200
            scale: PathView.iconScale
            opacity: PathView.iconOpacity
            z: PathView.iconOrder
            Image { anchors.fill: parent; source: modelData }
        }
    }

    PathView {
        id: view
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.bottomMargin: 150
        anchors.topMargin: 50
        pathItemCount: 7
        preferredHighlightBegin: 0.5                         //
        preferredHighlightEnd: 0.5                           // That should center the current item
        highlightRangeMode: PathView.StrictlyEnforceRange    //
        model:
            [
            "http://placeimg.com/200/200/any?rand=" + Math.random(),
            "http://placeimg.com/200/200/any?rand=" + Math.random(),
            "http://placeimg.com/200/200/any?rand=" + Math.random(),
            "http://placeimg.com/200/200/any?rand=" + Math.random(),
            "http://placeimg.com/200/200/any?rand=" + Math.random(),
            "http://placeimg.com/200/200/any?rand=" + Math.random(),
            "http://placeimg.com/200/200/any?rand=" + Math.random(),
            "http://placeimg.com/200/200/any?rand=" + Math.random(),
            ]
        delegate: delegate
        path: Path {
            startX: 0; startY: view.height/2
            PathAttribute { name: "iconScale"; value: 0.2 }
            PathAttribute { name: "iconOpacity"; value: 10.2 }
            PathAttribute { name: "iconOrder"; value: 0 }
            PathLine {x: view.width / 2; y: view.height/2 }
            PathAttribute { name: "iconScale"; value: 1.2 }
            PathAttribute { name: "iconOpacity"; value: 1 }
            PathAttribute { name: "iconOrder"; value: 8 }
            PathLine {x: view.width; y: view.height/2 }
        }
    }
}
```

Sure, if you really want to place current item in the center of the view you just have to change the path, i.e. move start point to the center etc.

Comment: If I move the start point ( startX in the middle of the screen ) i don't have any images on the left of that, and I want that. Your example is good, but i want my carousel in 2D, not 3D. How can I achieve that?

Comment: You just need to change the path as you want.

Comment: I've changed the example, check it now.

Comment: Yes now they are all centered. The same result I had with my example: all images displayed on one line but the currentItem ( or selected item ) is not at the center, it's always at the left!

Comment: Probably the problem is parity. You cannot center even count of items so one of them will be in the center.

Comment: I've read the documentation and it looks that I've found solution. See me edited answer.

Comment: How is `scale: PathView.iconScale` recognized in that context?

Comment: @folibis What is the parameter that specify the distance between the center item and the others?

Comment: @Mark, I guess then items are distributed evenly on the path, there is no parameter that you ask, all that depends on the path and items sizes.

Comment: Actually there is, I've just discovered it. I had to change, say: `startX: -view.width / 3` and last `PathLine {x: view.width * 1.3 ... `